# Вопрос по строкам C++

Tags: c++, строки

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string a="8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888";

    while (a.find("222")!=-1 || a.find("888")!=-1) {
        if (a.find("222") != -1) {
            a.replace(a.begin(), a.end(), '222', '8');
        }
        else {
            a.replace(a.begin(), a.end(), '888', '2');
        }
    }

    cout << a;

    return 0;
}
```

не могу понять почему ничего не выводи, само задание:
Исполнитель Редактор получает на вход строку цифр и преобразовывает её. Редактор может выполнять две команды, в обеих командах v и w обозначают цепочки цифр.

А)  заменить (v, w).

Эта команда заменяет в строке первое слева вхождение цепочки v на цепочку w. Например, выполнение команды

заменить (111, 27)

преобразует строку 05111150 в строку 0527150. Если в строке нет вхождений цепочки v, то выполнение команды заменить (v, w) не меняет эту строку.

Б)  нашлось (v).

Эта команда проверяет, встречается ли цепочка v в строке исполнителя Редактор. Если она встречается, то команда возвращает логическое значение «истина», в противном случае возвращает значение «ложь». Строка

исполнителя при этом не изменяется.

Цикл

ПОКА условие

последовательность команд

КОНЕЦ ПОКА

выполняется, пока условие истинно.

В конструкции

ЕСЛИ условие

ТО команда1

ИНАЧЕ команда2

КОНЕЦ ЕСЛИ

выполняется команда1 (если условие истинно) или команда2 (если условие ложно).

Какая строка получится в результате применения приведённой ниже программы к строке, состоящей из 68 идущих подряд цифр 8? В ответе запишите полученную строку.

НАЧАЛО

ПОКА нашлось (222) ИЛИ нашлось (888)

ЕСЛИ нашлось (222)

ТО заменить (222, 8)

ИНАЧЕ заменить (888, 2)

КОНЕЦ ЕСЛИ

КОНЕЦ ПОКА

КОНЕЦ

Comment: Интересный у вас **символ** — `'222'`...

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, вы хотели написать что-то вроде

```
string a="8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888";

size_t p222, p888;
while ((p222 = a.find("222")) != a.npos ||
       (p888 = a.find("888")) != a.npos)
{
    if (p222 != a.npos)
        a.replace(p222, 3, "8");
    else
        a.replace(p888, 3, "2");
}

cout << a;
```

Ну, а последовательность получающихся при этом строк имеет такой вид:

```
28888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
228888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
2228888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
88888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
288888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
2288888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
22288888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
2888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
22888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
222888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
28888888888888888888888888888888888888888
228888888888888888888888888888888888888
2228888888888888888888888888888888888
88888888888888888888888888888888888
288888888888888888888888888888888
2288888888888888888888888888888
22288888888888888888888888888
888888888888888888888888888
2888888888888888888888888
22888888888888888888888
222888888888888888888
8888888888888888888
28888888888888888
228888888888888
2228888888888
88888888888
288888888
2288888
22288
888
2
```

Comment: a что делает size_t&

Comment: Тип, возвращаемый `.find()`.